# SQL get all rows sorted without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
________________________
|id|value|date|approved|
-----------------------
```

What I need to be able to do is get each row where approved = 1. That part is obvious. For each occurrence of value, I only want the most recent row (sorted by date).

Meaning that with a table like this:

```
________________________
|id|value|date|approved|
-----------------------
|1 |Foo  | 5  |   1    |
|2 |Bar  | 6  |   1    |
|3 |Foo  | 8  |   1    |
-----------------------
```

I only want the rows with id 2 and 3.

I assume I need to use DISTINCT somehow, but I'm not sure how. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT value
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable m
ON      m.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.value = md.value
                AND mi.approved = 1
        ORDER BY
                mi.value DESC, mi.date DESC, mi.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `(value, date, id)` for this to work fast.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
select id, value, date, approved where (value, date) in (
   select value, max(date)
     from your_table
    group by value
);
```

Comment: You better replace it with a `JOIN`: `IN` is not very efficient with `GROUP BY` in `MySQL`. Also, what if there are duplicates on `date`?

Comment: @Quassnoi: thanks for the suggestion. Didn't know this wasn't performant on MySQL. If there are dups on `date`,  then you'll get both. Which is what I would think OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using GROUP BY will yeld better results. try something like this:

SELECT `id`, `value`, `date`, `approved` FROM table WHERE approved = 1 GROUP BY `value` ORDER BY `date`;

Comment: You can't `group by` like this. You need to `group by` all columns in your result set not having an aggregate function.

Comment: @Pablo: actually you can (in `MySQL`) but the results will be in arbitrary order (and not even guaranteed to belong to a single record).

Comment: @Quassnoi: you can do this in MySQL?! Wow... Weird. It's the first RDBMS that allow you to do this (that I know of).

Answer (score 0):

```
select  id, value, date, approved 
from mytable a
where approved = 1
 and date =
      (select max(b.date)
       from mytable b
       where b.approved = 1
       and b.value = a.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
      id,
      value,
      date
   from 
      ( select
              value, max( date ) as LastInstance
           from
              YourTable
           where
              approved = 1
           group by
              value ) PreQuery
      join YourTable 
         on PreQuery.value = YourTable.value
         and PreQuery.LastInstance = YourTable.LastInstance
         and YourTable.approved = 1
   order by 
      date
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this:

```
SELECT * DISTINCT FROM TABLA WHERE APPROVED = 1 ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Hope this helps you.